# Amend nginx.conf to listen on a UDP port and forward received messages to another IP address

Tags: windows, azure, nginx, udp, nginx-reverse-proxy

**CONTEXT**

I have a requirement to replace an Azure Classic Cloud Worker Role *(who's job is to listen on an dedicated fixed IP address e.g 99.99.99.99 udp port 10000)* with a Azure Resource Manager (ARM) resource that can host the static IPv4 address and forward UDP traffic.

**SOLUTION**

One solution under testing as a stepping stone is using NGINX on an Azure Windows Server VM and forward the data to another ARM resource hosting a Container Service.

**PROBLEM**

NGINX is completely new to me and I am struggling to get my head around configuring nginx.conf to

- listen on an IPv4 adddress
- UDP port 10000
- forward received messages to another IPv4 address

I have tried this from another stack article (below is a copy of my nginx.conf file up to the point where I implemented a change i.e from "stream"):

---

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

stream {
server {
    listen 10100 udp;
    proxy_pass juniper_close_stream_backend;
}
upstream juniper_close_stream_backend {
    server 99.99.99.99:10000;
}
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;
```

---

When making this config file amendment NGINX service will not start. Searching system logs I cannot find any error messages. Clearly the format of the config changes are incorrect. I can revert to the default file and the service starts.

**QUESTION**

How do I amend nginx.config to

1. listen on an IPv4 address
2. On UDP port 10000
3. Then forward received messaged to another IPv4 address ?

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think that an HTTP server is the solution for proxying non-HTTP traffic?  An example of a tool with this capability is `socat`.

Comment: Thankls for the ping. Docs suggest UDP load balancing is supported. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/